# How do I set the values along the diagonal matrix using eigen?

Tags: eigen

I am trying to construct a diagonal matrix using eigen and then set the values along the diagonal:

```
        Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic> diagonal_matrix(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            diagonal_matrix(i, i) = i * i + 2;
        }
```

However, this is not working because `diagonal_matrix` lacks the `()` operator. What is the proper way of setting the diagonal values of a diagonal matrix using eigen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This operator is not available because we would have to disallow calling it with (i,j) with i!=j and therefore such a function would make little sense. You have to use a more verbose approach that consists in taking the diagonal:

```
diag_mat.diagonal()[i] = ...;
```

Here, the .diagonal() member returns an expression of the diagonal as a 1D vector. You can also set it with high-level routines such as random of linear-spaced values. To reproduce your example:

```
diag_mat.diagonal() = ArrayXi::LinSpaced(5,0,4).square() + 2;
```